# How to implement a normal model admin like User model in django admin site

Tags: django, admin

As we know, After we add a new user in django admin site, page is redirected to editing profile, not user list page like other models. How to implement this in a normal model? For example I defined a model called Image and wanted to edit the image after the image had been uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following function into your admin class.

django/contrib/auth/admin.py:L139

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue='../%s/'):
    """
    Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage. It mostly defers to
    its superclass implementation but is customized because the User model
    has a slightly different workflow.
    """
    # We should allow further modification of the user just added i.e. the
    # 'Save' button should behave like the 'Save and continue editing'
    # button except in two scenarios:
    # * The user has pressed the 'Save and add another' button
    # * We are adding a user in a popup
    if '_addanother' not in request.POST and '_popup' not in request.POST:
        request.POST['_continue'] = 1
    return super(UserAdmin, self).response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
```